# How to create / activate a vertical scroll bar within a swal (SweetAlert)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I don't know if this is possible, but is there a possibility to activate or create a vertical scroll bar in a swal SweetAlert alert mode?

[SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)

The problem is that I am receiving a very large list of errors and exceeds the modal display limit.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/financeiro-gerenciar/remover-financeiro",
    type: "POST",
    data: { ids: selecedtRows },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        stopLoadGlobal();

        //Desmarcar o select do header
        $("#dtFinanceiroIndex .selectable-all").prop('checked', false);

        reload_dtFinanceiroIndex();

        if (result.success) {
            swal("Sucesso", result.message + " :)", "success");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //console.log(result.errors.value.errors)
            if (!result.success) {
                var errosRecebidos = result.message + "\n";

                $.each(result.errors.value.errors, function (key, value) {
                    errosRecebidos = errosRecebidos + '\n' + value

                });
            } 

            swal("Atenção", errosRecebidos + " :(", "error");

            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        stopLoadGlobal();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

[My SweetAlert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE33O.png)

CSS:

```
.sweet-overlay {
    /*z-index: 100000000000 !important;*/
    z-index: 999999999 !important;
}

.sweet-alert {
    /*z-index: 100000000000 !important;*/
    z-index: 999999999 !important;
}

.sweet-alert .swal-text {
    max-height: 6em; /* To be adjusted as you like */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post with the Ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [swal documentation](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#swal-text), you can customise the theming... To have a scroll bar in the swall body, I would use the `swal-text` class and define a `max-height` and `overflow-y:scroll` to it..

```js
// simulating the Ajax result here...
let errosRecebidos = ""

// supposing you have 324 errors lol!
for(i=0;i<324;i++){
  errosRecebidos += "Error #"+i+"\n"
}

swal("Atenção", errosRecebidos + " :(", "error")
```

```css
.swal-text{
  max-height: 6em;  /* To be adjusted as you like */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** using [SweetAlert for Bootstrap](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/), the idea is the same, but the class name is different. Here, instead of `.swal-text`, it's `.sweet-alert` and the "message" container (aside the title and buttons) is a `p`.

```js
// simulating the Ajax result here...
let errosRecebidos = ""

// supposing you have 324 errors lol!
for(i=0;i<324;i++){
  errosRecebidos += "Error #"+i+"\n"
}

swal("Atenção", errosRecebidos + " :(", "error")
```

```css
.sweet-alert p{
  max-height: 6em;  /* To be adjusted as you like */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.css">
```

Comment: How strange ... I added the CSS block, but it is not working as in your example. I tried to do ".sweet-alert .swal-text", but it didn't work either. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: That may be a version issue... I assumed you were using [sweetAlert.js](https://sweetalert.js.org/) and used the latest version (2.1.2). Now there also is [sweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), which is a bit different in the usage and certainly is different about the class names. Tell me what you are using exactly and I whill look. ;)

Comment: I am using a framework called Remark (https://getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/base/advanced/bootbox-sweetalert.html). It's an older version, I didn't find the version :(

Comment: It looks like swal-text doesn't exist. it must be another tag.

Comment: Okay... I think that is [SweetAlert for Bootstrap](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/). Try with the `sweet-alert` class.

Comment: ".sweet-alert" worked, but the scroll bar takes up the entire modal, including titles. Is it not possible to occupy only the body of the modal where the messages appear?

Comment: Okay! We're on the right track then... Try with `.sweet-alert p` ;)

Comment: Wowww it worked !!!! Thank you very, very much !!!! :) The solution was to use the following css: .sweet-alert p {
    max-height: 6em! important;
    overflow-y: scroll! important;
    width: 100%! important;
}

Comment: Update your answer and I will mark it as a solution :)